# vim: how to "resize" a window to half the size of vim screen?

Tags: vim, resize, command, window, size

In vim, I can set window size of NeedTree, tagList to some fixed size. But I wish that, when I open a subwindow using a hotkey, it will take up half the window size(if vsplit, take half the x-axis size, if hsplit, take half the y-axis size).

So my question is, for vimrc "resize" command, how to know the size of vim command line window and get the half of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:exec 'resize ' . winheight('.')/2`

Command line window height is `&cmdwinheight`, so: `:exec 'resize ' . &cmdwinheight/2`.

Comment: As a note, `&cmdwinheight` is the configured command window height, which sometimes isn't respected due to some strange bug in vim.